# REG ADD "REG_MULTI_SZ" separator with escaped "\" character

Tags: function, command-line, registry, addition

I have been trying to use the reg add command to add a "REG_MULT_SZ" entry to Registry.

Example1:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TESTKEY" /v "TESTVALUE" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" ^
   /d "TEST_ENTRY1\0TEST_ENTRY2\0TEST_ENTRY3" /f /reg:64
```

Example2:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TESTKEY" /v "TESTVALUE" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" /s "\0" ^
   /d "TEST_ENTRY1\0TEST_ENTRY2\0TEST_ENTRY3" /f /reg:64
```

The example 1 commands work because the default separator for that command is indeed `"\0"`, but if I try to use the `/s` command (example 2) to set the separator even if it is equal the default separator it doesn't work.

I tried to escape the `"\"` character using ... `/s "\\\0"` ... without success.

Does anybody know how to pass the `"\"` character to the `REG ADD "REG_MULTI_SZ"` command `/s`?

Best regards,

Aeolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg add /?

/s       Specify one character that you use as the separator in your data
         string for REG_MULTI_SZ. If omitted, use "\0" as the separator.
```

Specify **one character** (e.g. `€`) as follows:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TESTKEY" /v "TESTVALUE" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" /s € ^
   /d "TEST_ENTRY1€TEST_ENTRY2€TEST_ENTRY3" /f /reg:64
```

Note `^` and new line used merely for better readability, apply an one-liner

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\TESTKEY" /v "TESTVALUE" /t "REG_MULTI_SZ" /s € /d "TEST_ENTRY1€TEST_ENTRY2€TEST_ENTRY3" /f /reg:64
```

---

**Recapitulation:** if used `reg add ... /t REG_MULTI_SZ`

- with default separator (`/s` switch omitted) then:

  - `\0` is to  be used to separate multiple instances of data;
  - every `0` (zero) unpreceded with `\` (backslash) in data is taken literally.
- with `/s Ж` separator (where `Ж` is an only character, *hold even if defined* `/s 0`) then:

  - `Ж` is to  be used to separate multiple instances of data;
  - there is no chance to escape this *separator destiny* and use the `Ж` character literally in data.

---

**Example**: I can't document my explanation on escaping: based on experiments only. Example: imagine you should create a `REG_MULTI_SZ` registry value with next scenario with _numbered folders:

```
test\01gen
test\02gen
test\03gen
```

Then you **need** to override default separator. Override the default separator in `reg query` as well with `/se` switch (otherwise, the output could become a bit confusing):

```
d:\bat>set "_regKey=HKCU\Software\Test Key"

d:\bat>set "_regData=test\01gen€test\02gen€test\03gen"

d:\bat>REG ADD "%_regKey%" /v TESTVALUE /t REG_MULTI_SZ /s € /d "%_regData%" /f /reg:64
The operation completed successfully.

d:\bat>REG QUERY "%_regKey%" /v TESTVALUE

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    TESTVALUE    REG_MULTI_SZ    test\01gen\0test\02gen\0test\03gen


d:\bat>REG QUERY "%_regKey%" /v TESTVALUE /se @

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    TESTVALUE    REG_MULTI_SZ    test\01gen@test\02gen@test\03gen


d:\bat>
```

---

**Epilogue**: a thorny path to answer - see edit history (tl;dr).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. JosefZ! I must use just one character to separate the answers. But if I do not use a custom separator using the `/s` command the reg function defaults to `\0` which is a composed separator. How is it done? It is a reg function internal operation which can't be reproduced by user? If user choose to use `\n` as a separator, it could be done?